# Find the IP address using as3 and server side technology

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

I am trying to find the IP address using as3 in adobe Flash professional cs5.5 and I think it is not possible from AS3 without using any server side technology(maybe I am wrong).
But I don't know any server side technology like PHP..etc.

Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: The IP address of what? The client's external IP? The client computer's local IP? The server IP?

Comment: Sorry for not providing the correct information,
i want the server IP where my *.swf file will run.

Comment: swf doesn't run on the server, it run inside the client's browser.

Comment: Thank you,Lets make it simple,i need local machine ip address, using adobe flash professional cs5.5 and some server side technology,Help me.

Comment: The local IP address is usually not useful, especially for users who are behind a nat gateway of some sort (home router, cell data network, etc...). You can retrieve the external IP being used by poking at whatismyip.com and the like.

Comment: Thank you Marc B, I'll work on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the Local Machine using JavaScript. and also you can develop server side script which will retirve your local machine IP address from request header.

But as per your comments on your question I think you required your local machine IP. it will be get using javascript. But this IP address is not gateway or server side displayed one. Because in home or some fire wall / proxy user has different IP to access internet and local mahcine ip will be LAN IP.

and Javascript code you can call using the External Interface.

Please search for Javascript and ExternInterface code example you will find out many code example through google.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple and clean way to dynamically get the domain name, but not the IP, of the server hosting the SWF file.

You can use the `domain` property of the `LocalConnection` class.

try:

```
import flash.net.LocalConnection;
var lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
trace(lc.domain); // Outputs domain name of the hosting server, or `localhost` if ran locally.
```